# Error Handling in Jersey

Tags: exception, jersey

I have a Jersey application where I want to prevent the client from seeing any type of stacktrace if any type of Exception occurs.
How do I do this without changing any existing code?

Answer (score 1):

You can register an exception mapper as follows to handle all exceptions and customize the HTTP response:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```